# Tortoise view difference full of <<<<<<< .mine kind of labels

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am new to Tortoise SVN.

I have done changes on local files and meanwhile somebody updated the sources on the server.

So my projects .cpp files are full of

```
<<<<<<< .mine
```

and

```
>>>>>>> .r46
```

kinds of labels.

Reading documentation I understand it is the way SVN keeps traces on the mismatched sources between server and local.

I would have expected the diff tool in the Tortoise contextual menu to take into account these labels to display the diffs and help the manual merge. But instead I have a 'brutal' diff between the valid sources and dirty local file.

Is there a way to have the diffs displayed more nicely in the tool (auto hide the labels, and suggest modifications) ?

Also my code does not compile no more because of these labels :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the file with conflicts, then TortoiseSVN -> Edit Conflicts. It will show you text editor with yours and theirs version. Use it to resolve conflicts and save it as your local copy. More about this tool in here: [Resolving Conflicts](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-conflicts.html).

Comment: Thanks for helping. Actually I had not the "EditConflicts" option in the menu because I had not done SVN Update on the modified source. But the problem is still there : the diff tool for merging is still displaying all the "<<<<<<< .mine" for the local file. I think my local sources have been corrupted by my crazy noob clicks.